# How can I center the title of navigation drawer application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How can I change the title position of navigation drawer application (Android studio)?

Comment: share your xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here inside Toolbar inserted a textview with `gravity = "center"` and disable default title by java.

Try with below code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

      <TextView>
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Title Here"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

java code disable your title :

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```