# Centering the title in a custom layout with a navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar, android-toolbar

I am using toolbar with Navigation view.

[image]

I need to centre the text of this layout.

My Code Snippet -

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"

        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"

        android:weightSum="1"

        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_rl"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/purple_color">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_20"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"

                android:gravity="center"

                android:visibility="visible" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/right_icon_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_20"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_icon_1"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/right_icon_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_15"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_15"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/right_text_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_20"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_12"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Comment: Yeah . Are you using anything related to ToolBar ? Hamburger menu is set with ToolBar of its just an image ?

Comment: Look into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48880991/8448886

Comment: I am using `NavigationView`

Comment: I need to use `RelativeLayout` inside Toolbar for other views.

Comment: take help from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207491/remove-padding-between-hamburger-icon-and-toolbar/47207664#47207664

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664466/android-centre-title-with-navigation-drawer

Comment: @vm345 I need to user other views as well like Imageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use This Code :-**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Leadership"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_iv"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    />


                <!--<ImageView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/right_icon_2"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                    <!--android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"-->
                    <!--android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"-->
                    <!--android:visibility="gone" />-->

                <!--<ImageView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/right_icon_1"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                    <!--android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
                    <!--android:paddingLeft="15dp"-->
                    <!--android:paddingRight="15dp"-->
                    <!--android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"-->
                    <!--android:visibility="gone" />-->

                <!--<TextView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/right_text_1"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
                    <!--android:layout_centerInParent="true"-->
                    <!--android:layout_marginRight="20dp"-->
                    <!--android:text=""-->
                    <!--android:textColor="#000"-->
                    <!--android:textSize="12dp"-->
                    <!--android:visibility="gone" />-->
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: And what for other views?

Comment: you mentioned visibility="gone"

Comment: <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fnhwe"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                />

        Use other one like this

Comment: View visibility changes Dynamically.

Comment: no problem it will set automatically use this one for images :--

Comment: <ImageView android:id="@+id/fnhwe" android:layout_width="20dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:layout_gravity="end" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

Comment: pleasure to help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Set the textview's width to match_parent and then set it's gravity to center. Make sure you are setting android:gravity and not android:layout_gravity.

Comment: Tried this! BUT NO LUCK :(

Comment: Must remember that i am using `NavigationView`

Answer (score 1):

**Updated code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/header_rl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_iv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/right_icon_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/right_icon_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        android:paddingRight="15dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/right_text_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:text="Test"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Leaderboard"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Must remember that i am using `NavigationView`.

Comment: @ShoebSiddique then you need to post your whole xml code.

Comment: Full Code Added. Please check :)

Comment: Still same issue, i think we need to understand that this is only happening because of Navigation view